# How do I quit being a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

Due to life, etc, I don't feel that I can be an effective moderator anymore.   I don't see any obvious method within the system of quitting, though (barring just not responding to moderator flags, etc.).   What's the correct procedure to resign?

Comment: I thought moderators just had to email the (community) team to ask for a holiday etc, presumably the same would go for resignation.

Comment: @AndrewC: Yep, moderation is purely voluntary, so it's quite hassle free to step out/take a vacation.

Comment: That's what I ultimately did, but I didn't hear back from the person that I emailed.   I didn't know if he had moved on or what, and I couldn't find anything in the mod tools relating to resignations.   I also couldn't find anything with a search, but I may have been using the "wrong" keywords.

Answer (score 19):

The correct procedure is to email us at `community@stackexchange.com`. Or [one of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do), but that email  goes to the entire team and is therefore more reliable.

---

We got your request already. I'm sorry we didn't get back to you right away.

What's going to happen now is that we're going to line up a replacement for you. If you could stick around till then, that'd be fantastic. But if you'd rather not, no worries, please let me know and I'll take care of things sooner.

Comment: I can continue contributing as much as I have been over the last couple of months, without much problem.   I just feel like my community needs a higher level of involvement than what I can provide.

Comment: @baka Cool, thanks. We'll line something up as soon as possible.

Comment: Is this still valid answer? I tried to send an email to the email, but it bounced back.

Comment: @KamilSJaron Probably not. Lemme check with the CM team and see what the current process is.

Comment: @KamilSJaron The team's gonna figure out what they want to update this answer to, but for now - just use the "contact" form linked at the bottom of the site and it'll get to the right place internally.

Answer (score 4):

Please email the Community team (`community[at]stackoverflow.com`) and let them know (cc your co mods as well if you wish).

I have already let a community team member know (though I think that you still may have to send the email) in the Teacher's Lounge.

Note that it may be better to just go on a mod holiday (again, email the comm team for this) if you feel that you may be able to resume contributing in the future.

I'll be sad to see you go, you seem to have been a good mod.

Comment: There's [a new form they use for contact now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) but I don't know if that's the preferred way to contact them about this. I do know that emailing them works though.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Well, that's a bit more mainstream, and is probably for less priority things. Email is smoother, and IIRC the community@ email is basically for mod-related things only.